# Calculating demand function with MRS

Tags: microeconomics

$u(x_1,x_2)=x_1(x_2)^2$

I want to calculate the demand function $x_1(m,p_1,p_2)$ and $x_2(m,p_1,p_2)$.

$MRS(x_1,x_2)=-\frac{x_2}{2x_1}$, from $\frac{x_2}{2x_1}=\frac{p_1}{p_2}$ we get $x_1=\frac{x_2p_2}{2p_1}$ and $x_2=\frac{2x_1p_1}{p_2}$.

We have $m=x_1p_1+x_2p_2$, $x_1=\frac{m-x_2p_2}{p_1}$.

Now I tried inserting the equations into each other but didn't really get anywhere, it says $x_1(m, p_1, p_2)=\frac{m}{3p_1}$ and $x_2(m, p_1, p_2)=\frac{2m}{3p_2}$ in the solution sketch but I have no idea how to get to that.

Comment: Try a bit harder here: $x_2=\frac{2x_1p_1}{p_2}$ and $x_1=\frac{m-x_2p_2}{p_1}$ (you can use either equation to perform a substitution)

Comment: Ok, $x_1=\frac{2(\frac{m-x_2p_2}{p_1})p_1}{p_2}=\frac{2(m-x_2p_2)}{p_2}$? I also got this earlier when I tried but what now?

Comment: Oh I accidentally wrote $x_1$ instead of $x_2$ on the left of the equation but I still can't get any further

Comment: Ohhh I got it now I'm stupid